# Changing the center of a google map using AngluarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using **ng-map** it's an **AngularJS Google Maps Directive** created by [allenhwkim](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) to show a map on a html page and avoid coding a long javascript code.

> I want to change the center of the map when the user clicks on a
>   **hyperlink**.

Firstly , the map center is inialized with a value in the controller and Everything works perfectly  :

Html :

```
<ng-map zoom="12"  center="{{MyPosition}}" >  </ng-map>
```

AngluarJS controller:

```
$scope.MyPosition = [36.811, 10.087];
```

I tried to pass the longitude and latitude of the clicked item to a function in the controller that changes the value of 'MyPostion'

Html: ( **device.EventData[0].GPSPoint** contains a value like this : **longitude,latitude** )

```
<a data-toggle="modal" ng-click="changeMapPostion(device.EventData[0].GPSPoint)"> </a>
```

Function in the AngularJS controller :

```
$scope.changeMapPostion = function(NewPostion) {
    $scope.MyPosition = '[' + NewPostion + ']'
}
```

**the value of MyPostion is changed perfectly but the map center didn't change**

**How to solve this issue ? is it possible to change the center of the map with a javascript code**

Comment: now you need to reload map with new positions

Comment: thank you for you comment the answer of @Booster2ooo solved my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the Get Started of the lib you use, I see there is a way to get the (Google)map object. You can therefore simply use the setCenter method:

```
NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    map.setCenter(/* coords */);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer Now it works perfectly by changing 
map.setCenter(/* coords */);
with : 
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng) );